# Python Conditional Regex

Tags: python, regex

My program is given an object with parameters, and I need to get the parameters' values.

The object my program is given will look like this:

```py
Object = """{{objectName|
parameter1=random text|
parameter2=that may or may not|
parameter3=contain any letter (well, almost)|
parameter4=this is some [[problem|problematic text]], Houston, we have a problem!|
otherParameters=(order of parameters is random, but their name is fixed)}}"""
```

(all parameters might or might not exist)

I am trying to get the properties values.

In the first 3 lines, its pretty easy. a simple regex will find it:

```py
if "parameter1" in Object:
    parameter1 = re.split(r"parameter1=(.*?)[\|\}]", Object)[1]

if "parameter2" in Object:
    parameter2 = re.split(r"parameter2=(.*?)[\|\}]", Object)[1]
```

and so on.

The problem is with parameter4, the above regex (`property4=(.*?)[\|\}]`) will only return `this is some [[problem`, since the regex stops at the vertical bar.

Now here is the thing: vertical bar will only appear as part of the text inside "[[]]".

For example, `parameter1=a[[b|c]]d` might appear, but `parameter1=a|bc|` will never appear.

I need a regex which will stop at vertical bar, unless it is inside double square brackets. So for example, for parameter4, I will get `this is some [[problem|problematic text]], Houston, we have a problem!`

Comment: Try `parameter4=([^[}|]*(?:\[\[.*?]][^[}|]*)*)` if the param text does not contain any single `[`, `}` and `|` but may contain `[[....]]` substrings.

Comment: If parameter4 has a single `[[` `]]` you might use `parameter4=([^][|\n]+\[\[.*?\]\][^][|\n]+)`  https://regex101.com/r/1cQyco/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no perfect solution.

For other readers possibly reading this question in the future, the closest solution is, as pointed by Wiktor Stribiżew in the comments, `parameter4=([^[}|]*(?:\[\[.*?]][^[}|]*)*)`.

This regex will only work if the param text does not contain any single `[`, `}` and `|` but may contain `[[...]]` sub-strings.

If you want to understand this regex better, you might want to have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/bWVvKg/2

Answer (score 0):

Worked here when I removed the "?":

```
parameter4 = re.split(r"parameter4=(.*)[\|\}]", object_)[1]
```

I also changed the name of the variable to "object_" because "object" is a built-in object in Python

Best.

Comment: yes, that would work if there is only one more parameter after it, but if there are multiple parameters after the problematic parameter, that regex will catch all of them

Comment: I've tested with a few problematic parameters after parameter 4, and it worked as it should. As long each line ends with | or }.
If you put more than one parameter per line, it will be more complicated.